# Execute mongodb binaries on alpine linux

Tags: mongodb, docker, containers, busybox

I'm trying to run the binary mongodb in Alpine 64bit Linux for a docker container. But when running the command: `./mongodb` the following error occurs:

```
bash-4.3 # ./mongod
bash: ./mongod: No such file or directory.
```

For what reason it can not run it?

Comment: did you actually run "./mongod" instead of "./mongodb"?

Comment: I have run "./mongod"

Answer (score 12):

If you are still needing to use a package then there is now one available in the testing repository you can have a try with.

http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/x86_64/

```
echo 'http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing' >> /etc/apk/repositories

apk upgrade --update

apk add mongodb
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I performed the installation of mongodb, but at the moment to provide the service, errors are shown below. I think it's because of being in testing yet.
bash-4.3# mongod
Error relocating /usr/bin/mongod: _ZNSt13runtime_errorC1EPKc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/mongod: _ZNSt7__cxx1119basic_istringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1ERKNS_12basic_stringIcS2_S3_EESt13_Ios_Openmode: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/bin/mongod: _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE12_M_constructEmc: symbol not found

Comment: Hi, ye I tried it myself and then got errors like yourself. A bit premature - hopefully the developer will get it fixed and moved into the release repo soon. I tried building it from source myself but it proved to be quite time-consuming - especially since a lot of the tools - written in GO - need to be compiled separately.

Answer (score 7):

Because the binary distribution of MongoDB is linked against glibc, whereas Alpine Linux uses another C library:

```
/tmp/mongo/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.7/bin # ./mongod
sh: ./mongod: not found
/tmp/mongo/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.7/bin # ldd ./mongod
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f18f059f000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f18f059f000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f18f059f000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f18f059f000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x7f18f02ac000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f18f059f000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x7f18f009a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f18f059f000)
    ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f18efe0e000)
Error relocating ./mongod: gnu_get_libc_version: symbol not found
Error relocating ./mongod: __isinf: symbol not found
Error relocating ./mongod: backtrace_symbols: symbol not found
Error relocating ./mongod: __sbrk: symbol not found
Error relocating ./mongod: strtoq: symbol not found
Error relocating ./mongod: __register_atfork: symbol not found
Error relocating ./mongod: __isnan: symbol not found
Error relocating ./mongod: pthread_yield: symbol not found
Error relocating ./mongod: strtouq: symbol not found
Error relocating ./mongod: __finite: symbol not found
Error relocating ./mongod: backtrace: symbol not found
/tmp/mongo/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.7/bin #
```

So until someone builds an Alpine Linux package for MongoDB, your only option is to compile it yourself.